# How to test url in django

Tags: python, django, testing, django-urls, django-testing

I would like to test my url in django but I got error message.

here are my codes:

urls.py

```
url(r'^create/(?P<userName>[0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/$', views.create, name='create'),
```

test.py

```
from django.test import TestCase, Client

client = Client()


def test_create(self):
    """Test the url for "create"
    """

    response = self.client.get('/mission/create/' + str(self.userName))
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

and i would get this result:

```
FAIL: test_create (mission.tests.MissionUrlTests)
Test the url for "create"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/actinbox/mission/tests.py", line 122, in test_create
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
AssertionError: 301 != 200
```

Please help me with my codes here. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 24):

As @Selcuk said, you are missing the trailing slash in the URL. In order to avoid those typos and in case your URL will change some time, you should use [django's reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) function to get URLs:

```
# django 1.x
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
# django 2.x
from django.urls import reverse

def test_create(self):
    response = self.client.get(reverse('create', args=[self.userName]))
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Comment: The reverse is the most advisable option like @ilse2005 said.

Comment: In Django 2.0: `from django.urls import reverse`

Answer (score 9):

Your URL configuration requires a trailing slash (/) after `userName`. Since you did not include it in your test URL, Django first returns a redirect (301) to the correct URL.

Change the line

```
response = self.client.get('/mission/create/' + str(self.userName))
```

to

```
response = self.client.get('/mission/create/' + str(self.userName) + '/')
```

or better

```
response = self.client.get('/mission/create/{0}/'.format(self.userName))
```